# How can I export animation?

Tags: animation

I just made an idle pose.

I manipulated several key frames, but then I watched a tutorial video

I am supposed to generate keyframe for every frame.

I don't understand what he means by that.

Anyways, I would like to make animations separately

like run, idle, attack and etc.

But then again, in the video he makes all the poses straight

and doesn't seem to divide.

To sum up,

1. Procedure for exporting an animation (things I have to checkbox and etc.)
2. Is it better to make all at once then divide export? or else?

Screenshot is added so as to explain my situation.
[image: 1st]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select your armature and export in either BVH or FBX. This will export the animation of your armature in a commonly known format.

If you want to export parts of your animation separately then BVH is the way to go as you can specify to export a specific frame range as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I do not want my whole animation to be exported as one, but separately in order to divide them as run, walk, attack and etc.

Comment: @user37522 Answer updated. BVH is the way to go.